# How to Transform the Data in Ngrx Effects?

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx, ngrx-effects

this is the sample data i am getting from backend on a success action

```
[
{"id":"123456789","type":"CHK","routing":"783839","label":"lbl"},
{"id":"12345678923456","type":"SVNG","routing":"783839","label":"lbl"}
]
```

and i want to convert this data into the following data and make another subsequent call.

```
{ 
   accounts : [
      {"accountNumber":"123456789","accountType":"Current Account","routingNumber":"783839"}, 
      {"accountNumber":"12345678923456","accountType":"Savings Account","routingNumber":"783839"}
   ]
}
```

i have created these following simple util functions to transform the data and calling them in the final Effect mergeMap but not working.

```
function transformData(response) {
  console.log('transformData : ', response);
  const res = [];
  response.forEach((item) => {
    res.push({
      accountNumber: item.id,
      accountType: transformAccountType(item.type),
      routingNumber: item.routing,
    });
  });
  console.log('transformData end: ', res);
}

function transformAccountType(type) {
  let res = '';
  if (type === 'CHK') {
    res = 'Current Account';
  } else if (type === 'SVNG') {
    res = 'Savings Account';
  }
  return res;
}



TestEffect$ = createEffect(() =>
    this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType(TestAction),
      tap(() => {
        console.log('test action in que');
      }),
      mergeMap((action) => {
        console.log('data', action.data);
        console.log('transformed Data', transformData(action.data));
        console.log('action', action);

        return this.mockApi
          .postData({ accounts: transformData(action.data) })
          .pipe(
            map((res) => TestActionSuccess({ data: res })),
            tap(() => {
              console.log('test effect Finished');
            })
          );
      })
    )
  );
```

unfortunately i am getting undefined in the MergeMap when i call the the `transformData` function.

what is the right way to do this ?

here is [stackBlitzcode](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngrx-effects-example-bq8ez5?file=src%2Fapp%2Fstore%2Feffects.ts)

Comment: Your transformData function doesn't return anything... is void

Comment: @Andres2142 
:) lol ... how did i miss that ... i was in a -ve mind set and was thinking that we cannot use util functions in the effects :)